# javaScript: getElementById - Add variable with z-index and color

Tags: javascript

I have this string working:

```
document.getElementById(var_tab01).style.background = var_baggrund;
```

Now I would like to extend it with code like:

```
.value = var_plan.className = "xxx"
```

Display of the value from the variable var_plan (a 3-figure string) with styles from class xxx

```
.xxx{
z-index: 1;
color: white;
}
```

The class may only influence the var_plan variable.

Is that possible?? and how is the syntax?

Comment: Please check out my answer and mark green if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
var element = document.getElementById(var_tab01);
element.style.background = var_baggrund;
element.classList.add("xxx");
```

Comment: How can I include the value of the variable "var_plan"?
The variable "var_plan" is created previously and ready for use.

Comment: @Thoko put your full code where you create this variable and assign some value to it